# Django: Implementation of an API and determining errors

Tags: javascript, python, django

For the communication between the client (js) and server I would like to create an API. The API should be accessible by all client requests (js functions).

I would say that it is elegant when the response of the server is standardized. So that the interpretation at the client side can be also standardized.

For instance, my API module (*Python*) returns a JSON object with the default settings:

```
responseData = {
    "action_success": False,
    "data_container": None,
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "",
    }
}
```

Let's have a look at a example function `login` of the module `api`.

```
def login(request):
    # Get post data
    post = json.loads(request.body)
    # Get username and password
    username = post.get('username', None)
    password = post.get('password', None)
    # Initialize response data
    responseData = {
        "action_success": False,
        "data_container": None,
        "error": {
            "code": 0,
            "message": "",

        }
    }
    if username == '' or username is None:
        responseData.action_success = False
        responseData.error.code = 1
        responseData.error.message = "login.no_username"
        return JsonResponse(responseData)
    elif password == '' or password is None:
        responseData.action_success = False
        responseData.error.code = 2
        responseData.error.message = "login.no_password"
        return JsonResponse(responseData)
    # Check if username/password combination is correct
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        # User login
        login(request, user)
        responseData.action_success = True
        responseData.error.code = 0
        return JsonResponse(responseData)
    else:
        responseData.action_success = False
        responseData.error.code = 3
        responseData.error.message = "login.failed"
        return JsonResponse(responseData)
```

As you can see, I need several `if` statements to determine the error `responseData.error.message`. This should be used on the client side as feedback. *How the message is translated exactly  shouldn't be part of this question.*

The problem of determining the correct error message occures also when dealing with non-Django functions, for instance, if a file exist. So I have two questions:

1. Is there an alternative / easier way to determine the error message?
2. Is it a good idea to standardized the returned JSON-object? What is currently recommended for the usage and implementation of such an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create some ViewSets and Serializers in your back end (python), you can have a look at the documentation here:

[Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

[ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Depending on how you want to do it, your ViewSet will point to a specific Serializer such as (but not limited to):

- Index to return a list of objects
- Details for one object etc.
- etc.

If anything is wrong in the received JSON from your front end such as:

- Wrong data type
- Wrong data once compared to DB
- Other

Then the serializer will return an error object.

From there, the front end (your JS), you can read the included error message and then decide to alert the user of the issue. This will avoid having so many conditions in the backend for standard errors that can be identified.